# How can i enlarge a datatable in the R DT package?

Tags: css, r, pdf, r-markdown, dt

I am attempting to create an R markdown pdf_document but the tables I am incorporating are coming out too small on the page

As a first step, I have tried to increase the height and width (hoping the font size would increase accordingly) of the initial DT datable but I cannot even get that working

```
DT::datatable(head(iris, 20)
```

and

```
DT::datatable(head(iris, 20), height = '1200px', width='1200px')
```

both result in an image this size
[image]

which appears even smaller in the pdf output

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the table width to `100%` (the default is a fixed width `960px`), then *decrease* the figure width so text can be larger. This is because your PDF page width is fixed. The larger your screenshot is, the smaller the text will be. An example:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r fig.width=5}
DT::datatable(head(iris, 20), width = '100%')
```
````